# How do I deal optimal damage while dual-wielding?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Dual-wielding in Skyrim is... interesting. You can swing both hands individually (but not at the same time), or swing both hands together in a dual-attack.

The dual-attack can't be used while moving, but otherwise seems the premier way to deal damage with two weapons.

Then there's the dual *power* attack, which just completely wrecks #@$* up, but this requires stamina, so its not always an option.

Am I missing something here? Is there ever any reason where I *wouldn't* want to use the dual-strike? Is there some bonus to the regular swings when dual-wielding?

Comment: Dual strike consumes Stamina, because it's a Power Attack - its flat out superior to a standard Power Attack though, and is boosted by all the usual perks.

Comment: I'm not talking about the power attack - you can do a non power-attack with both weapons *also*.

Comment: Regular swings are easier to kite with, but I see as pointless. Your job is to walk up to the enemy and one-hit with a power attack. Against bosses, I usually kite a little with the one-hand, or when my stamina is low.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? You don't seem to be accepting that dual weapon attacks (power or not) are superior to single weapon attacks, so I'm not quite sure what you're looking for.

Comment: Think he's asking for quantitative analysis that hitting with both at the same time is strictly better than alternating left-right-left-right

Comment: @Hyppy - On the contrary, dual weapons attacks appear strictly superior to single weapon attacks. I'm asking if this is correct, and if there is any instance where I'd want to do anything else. Affe has the jist of it also.

Comment: How do you perform a normal dual attack and a power dual attack?

Comment: @Marcelo for a normal attack, press both the left hand and the right hand buttons simultaneously (left-click and right-click at the same time for PC). For a power attack, do the same thing, but hold the buttons down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the reasons why you wouldn't want to use the normal dual strike.

1. If you want to hit a moving target.  For instance, those annoying casters that are constant running away from you, since you can't pull it off while moving at the same time.
2. If you want to, for some reason, conserve the charges on the offhand weapon.  If your target is going to die in 1 hit, maybe you want to finish him off with a normal weapon in your off hand rather than the highly enchanted weapon in the main hand.
3. [This other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39515/are-there-any-advantages-to-using-dagger-dagger-as-opposed-to-dagger-sword) brings up the idea of using a dagger/something else combo.  Maybe if you were using a dagger/mace, for instance, you'll want to only use the mace on high health targets and the dagger for backstabs and quick kills.  **Dual attacking's main drawback is that it has a long cool down afterwards** So if there are a lot of small and weak enemies (or if you want to proc a weapon enchantment faster, such as using absorb health when your health is low), you'll want to just slash slash slash away with your dagger since its got a faster attack.

Comment: In practice, 1 seems to happen *a lot*.

Comment: @Raven yea, that is why I prefer the power attack, at least it moves you forward while performing it.  I rarely do the normal dual attack.  These days, I tend to go around with a shield and dagger since power bashing is so nice.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly anecdotally speaking, the dual-power-attack ravages pretty much everything. I've yet to find a reason to do anything else, short of one-off situation instances, like tapping someone with a soul-steal dagger to finish them without accidentally killing them with the other hand first.

I will sometimes use a fast one-handed strike if someone is low and I need it dead *right now*.

Comment: Again, I'm not talking about the power attack...