# What technique is best for attacking with dual wielded weapons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I deal optimal damage while dual-wielding?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40205/how-do-i-deal-optimal-damage-while-dual-wielding)

I am using duel wielded daggers and I tend to spam 2 handed power attacks to do the most damage. Is this the best technique, or should I be alternating left and right slashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using dual swords, and I would say it depends on the situation on what attack I am using. If I fight someone with a shield I try to attack on his none shield side. I'm not sure if that infact does more damage, but at least it makes the fighting scene look better from a roleplaying perspective.

I have also intend to completely miss when I do dual power attack, since its a bit slower than just using one side slash and the enemy tends to move around a lot. So I'm just using dual power attack when I got my enemy cornered or doesn't move around to much (like a dragon that just landed in front of your feet, hard to miss that one).

And one final thing I think about when I'm using dual weapons, is the weapons enchantments. One of my weapons have absorb health, so if my health going down, I'm just spamming that side attack. If you are up against a mage and have lightning enchantments on one of your sword, spam attacks with that one. Unless you can finish the mage of with a nice dual power attack of course.